# _pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from __newobj__ args has the wrong class in tensorflow project

Tags: python-3.x

code:
 # Write vocabulary#

vocab_processor.save(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "vocab"))

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 145, in 
    vocab_processor.save(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "vocab"))
  File "/home/chinu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/preprocessing/text.py", line 233, in save
    f.write(pickle.dumps(self))
_pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from **newobj** args has the wrong class

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem as you. May be you can check this [issue](https://github.com/dhwajraj/deep-siamese-text-similarity/pull/28) and the code changed in it helped me.
The detail in that pull request is to change the following code in `preprocesss.py` :

```
self.sup = super(MyVocabularyProcessor,self)
self.sup.__init__(max_document_length,min_frequency,vocabulary,tokenizer_fn)
```

into the next block.

```
sup = super(MyVocabularyProcessor,self)
sup.__init__(max_document_length,min_frequency,vocabulary,tokenizer_fn)
```

tips: Remember to use `2to3 -m filename` tool to change other python2 files into python3 ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the same project https://github.com/dhwajraj/deep-siamese-text-similarity - I had tried Python 3.x but this failed, had to change the Open file with encoding, change xrange to range etc and convert the code back - I ended up at the same issue as you. The code base is Python 2.x and after installing everything as indicated

```
numpy 1.11.0
tensorflow 1.2.1 (had to downgrade < 1.2 for Python2)
gensim 1.0.1
nltk 3.2.2
```